# Run method before suite in TestNG via XML

Tags: xml, testng

I have an XML TestNG suite:

```xml
<suite name="mySuite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
    <test name="myTest">
        <packages>
            <package name="mypack.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

and I'd like to run a method every time before the suite.

Is it possible to have something like this:

```xml
<suite name="mySuite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
    <before-suite>...</before-suite> <!-- Here I want to run a single method  -->
    <test name="myTest">
        <packages>
            <package name="mypack.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

?

Comment: If you use @beforeSuite method then no need to mention in XML file. But it will execute only once before suite

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options you have:

1. Use @BeforeSuite annotation on your method which you want to run before each suite
2. Implement the [ISuiteListener](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-g9b8da5b-121/javadoc/org/testng/ISuiteListener.html) onStart method, add the implemented listener to your xml in the listeners section.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation of the TestNG (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html), we don't have an option to specify the before suite method in testng.xml.

As an option, you can use before suite annotation as follows to satisfy the requirement.

```
public class UtilitiesTest {
     @BeforeSuite
     public void init() {
         // Initialize the system before the test suite.
     }
}
```

If you refer the documentation, you will find there are lots  of annotations such as `@BeforeTest, @BeforeClass, @BeforeMethod ...` might be helpful.

Note: You can place this class anywhere in the test suite.